# finding path of arbitrarily large weight in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

**Given a weighted directed graph with n vertices where edge weights are integers (positive, zero, or negative), determining whether there are paths of arbitrarily large weight can be performed in time -**

> O(n)
>
> O(n.log(n))  but not O(n)
>
> O(n^1.5) but not O(nlogn)
>
> O(n^3) but not O(n^1.5)
>
> O(2n) but not O(n^3)

I'm not understanding what algorithm to use as finding the longest path is a NP Hard problem. Though, the answer given is O(n^3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, you have to negate weights and then run the Floyd-Warshall algorithm. It takes O(n^3).

As mentioned [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/mfourman/teaching/mlCourse/notes/L15.pdf),

> The graphs must be acyclic, otherwise paths can have
>   arbitrarily large weights. We can find longest paths just by negating all of the
>   edge weights, and then using a shortest path algorithm. Unfortunately, Dijk
>   stra’s algorithm does not work if edges are allowed to have negative weights.
>   However, the Floyd-Warshall algorithm does work, as long as there are no
>   negative weight cycles, and so it can be used to find longest weight paths in
>   acyclic graphs.